# Linq reverse GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, grouping

I have this query:

```
from e in Employee
join t in TimeTable
    on e.Id equals t.EmpId
group new {e,t} by e.Id into g
orderby g.Key
select new 
{
  Emp = g.Key, 
  Items = g.Select(c => c.t.OtherTable.Somevalue).Distinct()
}
```

It works fine, but I need to reverse the grouping so that it would group all `Employees` on `OtherTable.Somevalue`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might like following this it will work

```
from e in Employee
join t in TimeTable
    on e.Id equals t.EmpId
group new {e,t} by t.OtherTable.Somevalue into g
orderby g.Key
select new 
{
  SomeValue = g.Key, 
  Emplyees = g.Select(c => c.e.Id).Distinct()
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius - thank you. I edited a little around the `select` for it to work - but still you solution was pretty clever. thank you

Comment: @JensKloster - Please remember to accept an answer when you are able.

Comment: @JensKloster - after some minute click on right sign below voting meter allow you to accept answer..